# Do I need CSP for a Web API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, content-security-policy

I'm pretty new to web development and just about understand how a Content Security Policy (CSP) can be used to detect and mitigate certain types of attacks, including Cross Site Scripting (XSS) and data injection attacks. This makes sense to me for a Web App issuing web pages. Would I still need to implement CSP for a Web API that just responds with data (json, xml etc.)?

Answer (score 10):

When in doubt, I look at what websites with a decent security track record do. For example, Github seems to serve up some of their API responses with a pretty strict CSP:

```
Content-Security-Policy:default-src 'none'
```